# can more then 1 web apps on the same domain but different host share authentication

Tags: authentication, cross-domain, servicestack

I have a servicestack web service web.mydomain.com where I use CustomUserSession and shared cache client.

How can my other servicestack web app  installed on app.mydomain.com use this service?

if I host them as virtual folders everything is fine, since cookies are shared across, but with different hosts (same domain) how can I make sure the cookies are shared? Seems that the cookies are stored upon return from auth/credentials with the web.mydomain.com and i would get 401 Unauthorize accessing app.mydomain.com since cookies are not going there.

I think at some point I saw someone mentioning that there is a web.config setting to specify how cookies are stored but cannot find it any more.

Is this the right approach?

Thank you
Mark